# WebStorm erroring for what appears to be no reason

Tags: webstorm

[image: image of text file]

I am not sure what is going on here. I have a brand new template that someone wrote and I plug it into my editor and get these lovely red squiggly lines. I cannot see any syntax errors so I'm thinking its the editor.

The first thing I see is on the `import` statement. Why is there a red squiggly there? It is telling me `statement expected` but that is a simple import statement! 
There is yet another after the const `serializers`. I will likely miss an actual error if these stay on here. I have tried changing the language and it is telling me that it knows its a Vue Component via the V symbol on the file in the Project tab.

I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I took a break and came back. Tried to load the component in Vue and it fails with the error.

```
unexpected character ' '
```

So it was a damn space! There were a few spaces, maybe it came from the fact that I copied the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying the [Zero Width Characters locator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7448-zero-width-characters-locator) plugin - it helps to visualize hidden control characters that might break the syntax highlighting and code execution